# Crear dos disparadores Delete, en la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo actualmente un `disparador` que actualiza al eliminar un dato de la tabla `pago_detalles`

```
update pagos a
    join pago_detalles di
      on di.idpago = a.id
      set a.pagado = a.pagado - di.monto
```

pero no me deje crear otro disparador `delete` entonces debo ponerlo ahi mismo pero no se como podria hacerlo.
el otro disparador es igual en delete pero es:

```
update pagos a
    join pago_detalles di
      on di.idpago = a.id
      set a.status = 1
```

como puedo unirlos para que sea en un solo `trigger` `DELETE`?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes separar las columnas con comas asi:

```
update pagos a
join pago_detalles di
  on di.idpago = a.id
  set a.pagado = a.pagado - di.monto,
      a.status = 1
```

Comment: pero como concatenaría otra tabla?